# What are the steps or phases to prepare a basement for finishing?

Tags: concrete, walls, basement, floor, finishing

I've got a small house with an old finished basement, and want to refinish it.

I've removed most of what's there (carpet, panel walls, old ceiling tiles, floor tile, etc) and am at a point where I need to prepare the basement for finishing.

What do I need to do to the concrete floor and walls (and maybe the rest of the area) before I start framing walls?

A few side notes on where I'm at:

Carpet glue / tile glue is on the concrete floor.

There are small chunks missing from the floor, and it's very uneven.  I plan to install tile or laminate over it.

As far as the walls go, no water gets in as long as my downspouts are in place.  If they're knocked off, water comes in one corner.